# Impact /clr compiler flag on native C++ application

Tags: c#, c++, .net, c++-cli, clr

My application is written in native C++. I want to use some C# code that deals with DB stuff.

I've been reading into the /clr flag and have some questions related to this.

1. I am aware that the compiler will add a thunk for each call to a
   managed function, however, I only need a single call. To minimize
   the effect of the /clr flag, I only want to compile a single cpp
   file with this flag. Would this affect the rest of the application?
2. What would be the effect of compiling my entire application (which is fully unmanaged) with the /clr flag? As long as the code is fully unmanaged (and calls no managed code), I would assume the compiler to hardly add any code, is that true?
3. I guess I don't need /clr:pure, as I don't want to switch to the C++/CLI framework, I only want access to some C# code in a very isolated part of the code, does that make sense?

Regards,

Ben

Comment: There is only one sane and proper answer: don't compile native C++ code with /clr in effect.  It's not like it won't work, but you'll only combine the disadvantages of both.  Put it in a static library project to fall in the pit of success.

Comment: @hans-passant put the wrapper in a separate unmanaged DLL, works like a charm, tnx

Comment: As far as I understand, with /clr, just because all *types* are unmanaged doesn't mean the code isn't (that part is commanded by `#pragma unmanaged`). Taking a random native C++ project and compiling it with /clr (without any change in the code) will result in all its code being compiled to MSIL instead of x86 machine code.